# Check if nD point lies within nD Hypersphere defined by n+1 points

Tags: geometry

I am writing some code where I need to be able to determine if a specific n-D point lies within a n-D hypersphere defined by n+1 points. The 2D version of this is clear to me; to check if a point, p,  lies within a circle defined by a triangle abc, one can just compute the determinate of the following matrix:

[a_x, a_y, |a|, 1]

[b_x, b_y, |b|, 1]

[c_x, c_y, |c|, 1]

[p_x, p_y, |p|, 1]

(|n|= n_x^2+n_y^2)

if the determinate is greater than zero then the point lies outside of the circle, if its zero, its on the circle, else it is within the circle.

I am hoping that this can scale up to how ever many dimensions I need, but I am unsure if it will as I do not know what would go in the additional column would be, obviously the new row would represent the new point.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your simple formulation has a flaw -- if I change points $A,B$ around, the determinant get multiplied by $-1$ so inside turned into outside.  It is either a feature or a bug, I don't know your intention.

To get the usual formulation,
$$
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
a_x^2+a_y^2 & a_x & a_y & 1\\
b_x^2+b_y^2 & b_x & b_y & 1\\
c_x^2+c_y^2 & c_x & c_y & 1\\
x^2+y^2 & x & y & 1
\end{pmatrix}=0
$$
is the Cartesian formula for the circle through $A,B,C$ (assuming the points are not collinear, i.e. the coefficient of $x^2+y^2$ is nonzero).  So a point is strictly outside (resp inside) the circle iff
$$
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
a_x^2+a_y^2 & a_x & a_y & 1\\
b_x^2+b_y^2 & b_x & b_y & 1\\
c_x^2+c_y^2 & c_x & c_y & 1\\
p_x^2+p_y^2 & p_x & p_y & 1
\end{pmatrix},
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
a_x & a_y & 1\\
b_x & b_y & 1\\
c_x & c_y & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
have the same (resp. opposite) sign.  (Remember we want the coefficient of $x^2+y^2$ to be 1 in the usual Cartesian equation of circle $\Gamma\colon C=0$ before saying $C<0$ is the inside and $C>0$ is the outside.)

This is the formulation that generalises: if the $n+1$ points $P^{(1)},\dots,P^{(n+1)}$ does not lie on a hyperplane, then point $P$ is inside/on/outside the hypersphere defined by $P^{(i)}$ if
$$
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\lvert P^{(1)}\rvert^2 & p^{(1)}_1 & \dots & p^{(1)}_{n+1} & 1\\
\lvert P^{(2)}\rvert^2 & p^{(2)}_1 & \dots & p^{(2)}_{n+1} & 1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\lvert P^{(n+1)}\rvert^2 & p^{(n+1)}_1 & \dots & p^{(n+1)}_{n+1} & 1\\
\lvert P\rvert^2 & p_1 & \dots & p_{n+1} & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has the opposite/zero/same sign as
$$
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
p^{(1)}_1 & \dots & p^{(1)}_{n+1} & 1\\
p^{(2)}_1 & \dots & p^{(2)}_{n+1} & 1\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
p^{(n+1)}_1 & \dots & p^{(n+1)}_{n+1} & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can solve for the center of the circumsphere of the simplex defined by the $n+1$ points, as follows:

Suppose your circumcenter is $c.$ Then

$$\|c - v_i\| = R^2,$$ for all $i.$ You don't know $R^2,$ but it does follow that

$$\|c-v_i\| = \|c-v_j\|,$$ for all $i, j.$ Expanding the square of the norm as inner product, you see that:

$$\|v_i\|^2 - \|v_j\|^2 = 2 \langle c, v_i - v_j\rangle,$$ for every $i, j.$ Now, by a translation, put $v_0$ at the origin, so you have
$$\|v_i\|^2 = 2 \langle c, v_i\rangle$$ for every $i=1, \dotsc, n.$
You can solve this system of linear equations for $c$ and then compute $R$ from the very very first equation above. Now, for your new point, just check that the distance to $c$ is less than $R.$